# Evaluating (not Sampling from) Beta Distribution in Numpy

Tags: numpy, probability-density

I am trying to calculate `Beta(x; a, b)` for many specific values of `x`, taking `a = 1, b = 25`. There is a beta function in numpy, namely `numpy.random.beta(a, b)`. But it samples from the beta distribution, rather than evaluating for specific values of `x`.

Any quick way around this, rather than having to code in the formula for beta?

Comment: So you want the beta pdf function?

Comment: Yes, the pdf

Ok, I tried: 

from scipy.stats import beta
print(beta.pdf(number,1,25))

But no matter what I put in for number, I always get 0.0. What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: try `beta(a, b).pdf(x)`

Comment: print(beta(1,25).pdf(1.5)) still yields 0.0 :(

Answer (score 8):

You are most likely looking for the [`scipy.stats.beta`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html) class. This lets you create a distribution for a particular pair of `a, b`  values:

```
dist = scipy.stats.beta(a, b)
```

You can then get the PDF and evaluate at any `x`:

```
dist.pdf(x)
```

`x` can be any numpy array, not just a scalar. You can evaluate the cumulative distribution in a similar manner:

```
dist.cdf(x)
```

You don't even need to create an instance object. This is especially useful if you want to evaluate the function once. In your particular use-case, it would probably be better to create an instance:

```
scipy.stats.beta.pdf(x, a, b)
```

The same applies to the CDF. The linked documentation shows lots of other things you can do with the distribution object.

`scipy.stats` contains many of other common [continuous distributions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#continuous-distributions) that all follow a similar interface. Any time you have a question related to basic statistics, scipy is the place to start.

Comment: @Warren. I don't think there's much ambiguity. A distribution is sampled according to its PDF, sort of by definition. I'd be happy to add the CDF as well. It's useful information, and there's a chance you may be right.

Comment: how to calculate PDF between two probabilities? I've tried dist.pdf(x2) - dist.pdf(x1) however it doesn't seem correct...

Comment: @haneulkim. I have no idea what that means. Consider asking a question with an MCVE. You can ping me here when you do if you want me to take a look.

Comment: @haneulkim coming back to your question some years later, I'm pretty sure you want the difference between the CDFs, which gives you the area of the PDF between those points.